# Incorrect beviour of button for action at the first time

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

The indicator always animates to the position under the most left button for the first time when any one of the four buttons is tapped. But what I want to see is that the indicator slides to a position right under the button that is just tapped. These four buttons are tagged as 0, 1, 2, 3 in the storyboard. Why? Thank you in advance!

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var weatherBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tourismBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tectonicsBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var foodBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var indicator: UIImageView!

    var btnsArray: [UIButton]!
    let tin = UIColor(red: 145/255, green: 145/255, blue: 145/255, alpha: 1)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        btnsArray = [weatherBtn, tourismBtn, tectonicsBtn, foodBtn]

        indicator.image = UIImage().solidColor(.black, size: indicator.frame.size)
    }

    @IBAction func topicBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        indicate(button: sender)
    }


    func indicate(button: UIButton) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.indicator.center.x = (button.superview?.frame.minX)! + button.frame.width * 0.5 * (2 * CGFloat(button.tag) + 1)
        }

        for btn in btnsArray {
            btn.titleLabel?.textColor = tin
        }
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func solidColor(_ color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Better if you use this -> https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/shviewpagerexample

Comment: @dahiya_boy Thanks! But i’m trying to just implement the code I have now. Without cocoa pods. :)

Comment: Are you using constraints when you lay this out in storyboard? If so, you should create `IBOutlet`s for the constraints and change the `.constant` value. Mixing constraints with explicit frame values will be problematic.

Comment: @DonMag Yes indeed. I’ve solved the problem now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using auto-layout constraints...

For your "indicator" `UIImageView`, set width and height constraints, and a vertical spacing constraint to the bottom of your Weather button.

Then, constrain it centered horizontally to your Weather button.

Add an IBOutlet for that centerX constraint:

```
@IBOutlet var indicatorCenterXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then, when you want to move the "indicator":

```
    // deactivate indicator's current centerXAnchor
    self.indicatorCenterXConstraint.isActive = false

    // re-init to center aligned to selected button
    self.indicatorCenterXConstraint = self.indicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerXAnchor)

    // set it active
    self.indicatorCenterXConstraint.isActive = true

    // animate it into place
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

So, each time you tap a "menu" button, you deactivate the current centerXAnchor, re-init it to the centerXAnchor of the tapped button, re-activate it, and animate it.

Here's the full class:

```
class MenuMainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var weatherBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tourismBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tectonicsBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var foodBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var indicator: UIImageView!

    // outlet to control the position of the indicator
    @IBOutlet var indicatorCenterXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var btnsArray: [UIButton]!
    let tin = UIColor(red: 145/255, green: 145/255, blue: 145/255, alpha: 1)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        btnsArray = [weatherBtn, tourismBtn, tectonicsBtn, foodBtn]

        indicator.image = UIImage().solidColor(.black, size: indicator.frame.size)

        // init button title colors
        for btn in btnsArray {
            btn.setTitleColor(tin, for: .normal)
        }
        // set first button to "active" color
        weatherBtn.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)

    }

    @IBAction func topicBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        indicate(button: sender)
    }


    func indicate(button: UIButton) {
        // deactivate indicator's current centerXAnchor
        self.indicatorCenterXConstraint.isActive = false

        // re-init to center aligned to selected button
        self.indicatorCenterXConstraint = self.indicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerXAnchor)

        // set it active
        self.indicatorCenterXConstraint.isActive = true

        // animate it into place
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

        // update button title colors
        for btn in btnsArray {
            btn.setTitleColor(tin, for: .normal)
        }
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

and, by the way, instead of creating a solid-color image for your "indicator" imageView, you can use a plain `UIView` with `.backgroundColor = .black`.

Comment: Thank you so much! You made it really clear and detailed for me! And also thanks for the additional implementation!